# how to optimize my sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, reportingservices-2005

I want to optimize my sql query which i have written earlier (please see below attached sql query).  This query is straight forward and very simple but this needs to be modified as it is failing at performance test, and I know the query is slow.  My team lead did mention to me to use 'Pivoting' in the query but i didn't catch his point how to pivot.  Please can some one help me in this regard.

```
Declare @tempTable Table(
DataSourceColumID int, fDataSourceID int, seqNum int, ColName varchar(50), HeaderName varchar(50)
)
Insert into @tempTable 
(DataSourceColumID, fDataSourceID,seqNum, ColName,HeaderName) 
Select 101,1,2,'col1', 'column 1'
Union ALL
Select 102,1,1,'col2', 'column 2'
Union All
Select 103,1,3,'col6', 'column 6'
Union All
Select 104,1,4,'col50', 'column 50'
select * From @tempTable 

Declare @ColumnOrderTable table (col_A varchar(10),col_B varchar(10),col_C varchar(10),col_D varchar(10),col_E varchar(10),col_F varchar(10),col_G varchar(10))
Insert into @ColumnOrderTable (col_A ,col_B ,col_C ,col_D ,col_E ,col_F ,col_G )
select 
Case When seqNum=1 then HeaderName else '' end as col_A,
Case When seqNum=2 then HeaderName else '' end as col_B ,
Case When seqNum=3 then HeaderName else '' end as col_C ,
Case When seqNum=4 then HeaderName else '' end as col_D ,
Case When seqNum=5 then HeaderName else '' end as col_E ,
Case When seqNum=6 then HeaderName else '' end as col_F, 
Case When seqNum=7 then HeaderName else '' end as col_G
from @tempTable

select max(col_A) as col_A ,max(col_B) col_B,max(col_C) col_C,max(col_D) col_D,max(col_E) col_E,max(col_F) col_F,max(col_G) col_G  From @ColumnOrderTable
```

Comment: Have you read this? Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of selecting into a @ColumnOrderTable, you can ommit that step and use a subselect.

#### Simplified original statement

```
SELECT  MAX(col_A)
        , MAX(col_B)
        , MAX(col_C)
        , MAX(col_D)
        , MAX(col_E)
        , MAX(col_F)
        , MAX(col_G)
FROM    (
          SELECT
            Case When seqNum=1 then HeaderName else '' end as col_A,
            Case When seqNum=2 then HeaderName else '' end as col_B ,
            Case When seqNum=3 then HeaderName else '' end as col_C ,
            Case When seqNum=4 then HeaderName else '' end as col_D ,
            Case When seqNum=5 then HeaderName else '' end as col_E ,
            Case When seqNum=6 then HeaderName else '' end as col_F, 
            Case When seqNum=7 then HeaderName else '' end as col_G
          FROM  @tempTable
        ) t
```

The subselect itself can be ommitted by converting this statement using the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) function.

#### Using PIVOT

```
SELECT  col_A = [1]
        , col_B = [2]
        , col_C = [3]
        , col_D = [4]
        , col_E = [5] 
        , col_F = [6]
        , col_G = [7]
FROM    (SELECT seqNum, HeaderName FROM @tempTable) t
PIVOT   (MAX(HeaderName) FOR seqNum IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])) pt
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach sucks on many ways:

- First you do a select into a temp table. This means all data has to be copied before the second step stops.
- Then you copy again into another temp table
- And then finally you make a max.

This is a beginner nonono.

- Eliminate BOTH temp tables. Just get rid of them. Even without using pivot or something there simply is no need for that. You can select (max) directly on the pass through SQL. Temp tables are BAD as they mean ALL data must be processed first - in your case you process all data THREE Times. The optimizer can not optimize that away.

Second, check Pivot. There is documentation ;) Look it up, come back with specific questions.

Comment: I assume OP only uses one temptable. The other one is provided for our benefit to provide a runnable script(a good thing).

Comment: So he still can possibly cot down his runtime by what - 99%? Depends how much data he needlessly processes into the temp table as there are no filter conditions.

Comment: Hi Lieven,
Thank you so much for query provided, now i understood how to use PIVOT and it is correctly getting details as required.  You are right, I just created a temp table for understanding purpose only -- just to insert some values and test against it.  Thanks a lot for giving me answer so quicklly.

Comment: @desi - don't mention it but you've attached the comment to the wrong answer :)